# How to do POS tagging using SVM in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, svm, pos-tagger

I want to do POS tagging using SVM with non-English corpus in Python.
It looks like Python does not support tagging using SVM yet (http://www.nltk.org/_modules).

scikit-learn has a SVM module. So I installed scikit-learn and use it in Python but I cannot find any tutorials about POS tagging using SVM.

I really have no clue what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be an SVM? NTLK has built-in tools to do POS tagging: [Categorizing and Tagging Words](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

If you want to use a custom classifier, look here: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html, Ctrl+F "svm", NTLK provides a wrapper for scikit-learn algorithms called `SklearnClassifier`. Then take a look here http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html, Ctrl+F "classifier", there is a class `nltk.tag.sequential.ClassifierBasedPOSTagger`which apparently can use wrapped up classifiers from sklearn.

I haven't tried this but it might work.

EDIT:
It should work like this:

```
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SklearnClassifier(SVC(),sparse=False)
cpos = nltk.tag.sequential.ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents,classifier_builder
= lambda train_feats: clf.train(train_feats))
```

The only problem is that sklearn classifiers take numerical features only, so you need to convert yours somehow.

Comment: Thanks, hellpanderrr. I tried other tagger (CRF, TBL, HMM,...) and wanted to use SVM. I used this wrapper but still cannot do any POS tagging.

Comment: With other taggers in Python, you only need training data to train, then you can use tag method and evaluate method. But when I use SVM of scikit-learn or `SklearnClassifier`, I cannot find any method to train or tag.